# Help understanding this Proof - Any subset of n dimensional space containing more than n vectors must be dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

[image: proof of theorem]

I understand that when you have more unknowns than equations, you end up with infinitely many solutions. This would imply that a nontrivial solution exists, and thus, the system is linearly dependent.

However, my confusion lies in that the proof states that the unknowns are the $d$'s.
It seems like there are $r$ of these unknowns, and also $r$ equations.

Can someone please explain why there are more unknowns than equations in this case? Thanks!

Comment: There is a typo in the system of equations. It should go like this: $\begin{array}{rcl}d_1c_{11}+d_2c_{21}+\ldots+d_rc_{r1}&=&0\\d_1c_{12}+d_2c_{22}+\ldots+d_rc_{r2}&=&0\\&\vdots&\\d_1c_{1n}+d_2c_{2n}+\ldots+d_rc_{rn}&=&0\end{array}$ - which is a system of $n$ equations with $r>n$ unknowns.

Comment: Try to make up a example of $W$ and $V$,  and you can see why.

Comment: No, actually I believe that the notes have the correct summation. However, they have accidentally deduced the wrong system of equations from that sum (I think it's probably a typo). See my below answer for more details.

Comment: Each equation in the system comes (or, at least, *should* come) from a coefficient multiplying one of the $\bf u_j$'s.

Comment: @coomerdoomer Stop doing this edit to xxxxxx. If you do not want your question to be shown anymore, just delete it.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, I think there is a typo in the notes you are referring to. In the system they've actually written in the notes, you are absolutely correct in pointing our there are the same number of unknowns as equations.

However, the system of equations they really want to write down is
$$
\begin{cases}
d_1c_{11}+ d_2c_{21} + \cdots + d_rc_{r1} = 0 \\ \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots \\ d_1c_{1n}+ d_2c_{2n} + \cdots + d_rc_{rn} = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Here, there are $n$ equations and $r$ unknowns (treating $d_j$'s as the unknowns). Since we assumed that $r > n$, this would imply that there are more unknowns than equations.

This is the correct system to be thinking about since $c_1u_1 + \cdots c_nu_n = 0$ if and only if $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$ (this is because $u_1, \dots, u_n$ is a basis, and hence is linearly independent). Note that we want to find $d_1, \dots, d_r$ not all zero such that $\sum_{j = 1}^r d_j(c_{j1}u_1 + \cdots + c_{jn}u_n) =0$. However, gathering all the terms with $u_j$ in this sum and adding the coefficients we get
$$
\left (
\sum_{j =1}^r d_jc_{j1}\right )u_1 + \cdots + \left (
\sum_{j =1}^r d_jc_{jn}\right )u_n = 0.$$
Finding $d_j$ that make the above equation equal to $0$ is the same thing as finding $d_j$ that make each coefficient $0$ since a linear combination of $u_j$'s is equal to $0$ if and only if all the coefficients are $0$. This implies that we want to find a solution to the above system.